# Javascript that uses substring to split user input into two textareas depending on multiple If statement it only considers one if statement

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

i am kind of new to it all but i have an input field where the user would input a string and i need it to come out split in the right final field depending on numerical and nonnumerical part of the string and no matter what i do it at runtime it only goes through the first IF statement regardless of the length which is my IF statement criteria

```
<pre>

<p>Click the button to extract characters from the string.</p>

<p id="demo1"></p>
<form>

    <input id="userInput"><br>
    <label> Non Numeric</label><textarea id="nonNumeric"> </textarea>
    <label> Numeric</label><textarea id="numeric"> </textarea> <br>
    <label> Numeric Result</label><textarea id="numericResult"> </textarea>
</form>
<button onclick="seventeenDigitChasSearch()">Try it</button>

</pre>
```

````
        <script>
    function seventeenDigitChasSearch() {
            var str =   document.getElementById("userInput").value ;
            var nonNumeric = str.substring(0, 14); //checks between index 0 and 13
            var numeric = str.substring(14, 17);  ////checks between index 14 and 17
     
        document.getElementById("nonNumeric").innerHTML = nonNumeric;
        document.getElementById("numeric").innerHTML = numeric;
      //convert the numeric number to an int value before evaluating it
            intNumeric =parseInt(numeric) ;
    
        if (intNumeric.toString().length = 17) {
    
            nonNumeric = str.substring(0, 14);
            numeric = str.substring(14, 17);
            document.getElementById("nonNumeric").innerHTML = nonNumeric;
            document.getElementById("numeric").innerHTML = numeric;
            document.getElementById("numericResult").innerHTML = "Yaay value is  within our of preferred";
            }
    
        else if (intNumeric.toString().length = 10) {
    
            
            numeric = str.substring(0, 10);
            document.getElementById("nonNumeric").innerHTML = "none";
            document.getElementById("numeric").innerHTML = numeric;
            document.getElementById("numericResult").innerHTML = "10 Range";
    
        }
          else if (intNumeric == null) 
    
          {
             document.getElementById("numericResult").innerHTML = "Faulty out of ranged numbers";
          }
    
    
    } ```
````

Comment: Equals in javascript is `==` or `===` - you're assigning within your `if` statements. `parseInt` will also never return null. I also don't understand how you expect `numeric` to ever have a length of 10 or 17 when its taken from `str.substring(14, 17)`

Comment: If you want help to actually get this working, can you describe what your code is actually trying to do

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to assign 17 to the string length

`intNumeric.toString().length = 17`

To compare you need to use `==` or `===`

Change the if to `if (intNumeric.toString().length == 17)` and test again

Here is a reference to the different operators on js. Look at assignation vs comparasion https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

Comment: This is only scratching the surface of the problems with this code

Comment: maybe you are right @Jamiec , I see your comment after post, but think that the `17` Is a testing value just trying to not go into the first if. So, I think that this is the main problem

Comment: But it cant go into the second either (cant be 10) nor can it get into the 3rd as it'll never be null. I think the OP needs to clarify the question somewhat for us to give a good answer.

Answer (score -1):

You are making an assignment on if statement. Use = for assignments and == or === for comparisons.

In your case the evaluation of the expression  `intNumeric.toString().length = 17`  return a truthy value.

[In JavaScript, a truthy value is a value that is considered true when encountered in a Boolean context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)